# Magento error while adding products

Tags: product, error, magento-2.1

While adding products to my magento2 store I get this problem:

[image]

This is my var report file:

```
a:4:{i:0;s:37:"Object DOMDocument should be created.";i:1;s:5978:"#0  /home/lagjjail/public_html/kushtrim.net/myphones/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/UiComponent/Config/Reader.php(95):Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\Config\DomMerger->getDom()

#1 /home/lagjjail/public_html/kushtrim.net/myphones/vendor/magento/module-ui/Model/Manager.php(258): Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\Config\Reader->read()

#2 /home/lagjjail/public_html/kushtrim.net/myphones/vendor/magento/module-ui/Model/Manager.php(166): Magento\Ui\Model\Manager->prepare('review_listing')

#3 /home/lagjjail/public_html/kushtrim.net/myphones/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/UiComponentFactory.php(144): Magento\Ui\Model\Manager->prepareData('review_listing')

#4 /home/lagjjail/public_html/kushtrim.net/myphones/vendor/magento/module-ui/Controller/Adminhtml/Index/Render.php(30): Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponentFactory->create('review_listing')

#5 /home/lagjjail/public_html/kushtrim.net/myphones/var/generation/Magento/Ui/Controller/Adminhtml/Index/Render/Interceptor.php(24): Magento\Ui\Controller\Adminhtml\Index\Render->execute()

#6 /home/lagjjail/public_html/kushtrim.net/myphones/vendor/magento/framework/App/Action/Action.php(102): Magento\Ui\Controller\Adminhtml\Index\Render\Interceptor->execute()

#7 /home/lagjjail/public_html/kushtrim.net/myphones/vendor/magento/module-backend/App/AbstractAction.php(226): Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))

#8 /home/lagjjail/public_html/kushtrim.net/myphones/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(74): Magento\Backend\App\AbstractAction->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))

#9 /home/lagjjail/public_html/kushtrim.net/myphones/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(70): Magento\Ui\Controller\Adminhtml\Index\Render\Interceptor->___callParent('dispatch', Array)

#10 /home/lagjjail/public_html/kushtrim.net/myphones/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(63): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->invokeNext('Magento\\Ui\\Cont...', 'dispatch', Object(Magento\Ui\Controller\Adminhtml\Index\Render\Interceptor), Array, 'adminAuthentica...')

#11 /home/lagjjail/public_html/kushtrim.net/myphones/vendor/magento/module-backend/App/Action/Plugin/Authentication.php(143): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))

#12 /home/lagjjail/public_html/kushtrim.net/myphones/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(67): Magento\Backend\App\Action\Plugin\Authentication->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\Ui\Controller\Adminhtml\Index\Render\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))

#13 /home/lagjjail/public_html/kushtrim.net/myphones/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->invokeNext('Magento\\Ui\\Cont...', 'dispatch', Object(Magento\Ui\Controller\Adminhtml\Index\Render\Interceptor), Array, 'adminMassaction...')

#14 /home/lagjjail/public_html/kushtrim.net/myphones/vendor/magento/module-backend/App/Action/Plugin/MassactionKey.php(33): Magento\Ui\Controller\Adminhtml\Index\Render\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))

#15 /home/lagjjail/public_html/kushtrim.net/myphones/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(142): Magento\Backend\App\Action\Plugin\MassactionKey->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\Ui\Controller\Adminhtml\Index\Render\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))

#16 /home/lagjjail/public_html/kushtrim.net/myphones/var/generation/Magento/Ui/Controller/Adminhtml/Index/Render/Interceptor.php(52): Magento\Ui\Controller\Adminhtml\Index\Render\Interceptor->___callPlugins('dispatch', Array, Array)

#17 /home/lagjjail/public_html/kushtrim.net/myphones/vendor/magento/framework/App/FrontController.php(55): Magento\Ui\Controller\Adminhtml\Index\Render\Interceptor->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))

#18 /home/lagjjail/public_html/kushtrim.net/myphones/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(74): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))

#19 /home/lagjjail/public_html/kushtrim.net/myphones/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(70): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->___callParent('dispatch', Array)

#20 /home/lagjjail/public_html/kushtrim.net/myphones/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->invokeNext('Magento\\Framewo...', 'dispatch', Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor), Array, 'install')

#21 /home/lagjjail/public_html/kushtrim.net/myphones/vendor/magento/framework/Module/Plugin/DbStatusValidator.php(69): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))

#22 /home/lagjjail/public_html/kushtrim.net/myphones/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(142): Magento\Framework\Module\Plugin\DbStatusValidator->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))

#23 /home/lagjjail/public_html/kushtrim.net/myphones/var/generation/Magento/Framework/App/FrontController/Interceptor.php(26): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->___callPlugins('dispatch', Array, Array)

#24 /home/lagjjail/public_html/kushtrim.net/myphones/vendor/magento/framework/App/Http.php(135): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))

#25 /home/lagjjail/public_html/kushtrim.net/myphones/vendor/magento/framework/App/Bootstrap.php(258): Magento\Framework\App\Http->launch()
#26 /home/lagjjail/public_html/kushtrim.net/myphones/index.php(39): Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Http))

#27 {main}";s:3:"url";s:139:"/myphones/admin/mui/index/render/key/da73d8fc562ce967b9d8f128927dce12e2d03178a186aa6129e39cb70c2b23e9/?namespace=review_listing&isAjax=true";s:11:"script_name";s:19:"/myphones/index.php";}
```

This courses that I can add products to the cart and checkout but the checkout process can't proceed so you can't add addresses and go further. Any ideas on how I can resolve this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seemed That the problem was on disabling some of the magento modules on `Stores > configuration > Advanced > Advanced.` One of these coursed the Error. After enabling them all again and testing the adding of products the error was gone.

Answer (score 0):

Run this command on your terminal to **enable all** modules and to do the deploy again:

```
alias mage="php -d memory_limit=-1 -f bin/magento"

chmod -R 775 pub/static/ var/ pub/media/ &&
rm -rf var/view_preprocessed/ var/cache/ var/page_cache/ var/tmp/ var/generation/ pub/static/frontend/ ;

mage module:enable --all

mage cache:clean &
mage cache:flush &
mage indexer:reindex &
mage setup:upgrade &&
mage setup:static-content:deploy ; mage setup:static-content:deploy -f;
mage setup:db-data:upgrade &&
mage dev:source-theme:deploy &&
chmod -R 775 pub/static/ pub/media/ var/
```

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/318269/57334 any help thanks @Rafael Corrêa Gomes