# Any help - Magento 2.3 - After migration Add Product via admin return Fatal error, any help for this error

Tags: product, magento2.3.4, product-edit

Installed Magento 2.3.4 using Github Installation, After migration from Magento version 1.9.2.3 to 2.3.4 If [click Add Product](https://snipboard.io/jXOcwz.jpg) i am getting the following error,

[image]

Errors:

System.log :

```
[2020-09-18 10:37:04] main.INFO: Consumer "async.operations.all" skipped as required connection "amqp" is not configured. Unknown connection name amqp [] []
[2020-09-18 10:38:03] main.INFO: Consumer "async.operations.all" skipped as required connection "amqp" is not configured. Unknown connection name amqp [] []
[2020-09-18 10:38:04] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'product.reviews' element cannot be added as child to 'product_tabs', because the latter doesn't exist [] []
[2020-09-18 10:38:06] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'catalog.compare.sidebar' element cannot be added as child to 'sidebar.additional', because the latter doesn't exist [] []
[2020-09-18 10:38:06] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'sale.reorder.sidebar' element cannot be added as child to 'sidebar.additional', because the latter doesn't exist [] []
[2020-09-18 10:38:06] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'wishlist_sidebar' element cannot be added as child to 'sidebar.additional', because the latter doesn't exist [] []
[2020-09-18 10:38:06] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'footer.custom.block' tries to reorder itself towards 'copyright', but their parents are different: 'footer.content.bottom' and 'footer' respectively. [] []
[2020-09-18 10:38:06] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'authorization-link-login' tries to reorder itself towards 'register-link', but their parents are different: 'header.links' and 'top.links' respectively. [] []
[2020-09-18 10:38:06] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'store_language' tries to reorder itself towards 'store_switcher', but their parents are different: 'header.panel.right' and 'header.panel.store' respectively. [] []
```

debug.log:

```
[2020-09-18 10:37:02] main.INFO: Cron Job catalog_product_outdated_price_values_cleanup is run [] []
[2020-09-18 10:37:02] main.INFO: Cron Job catalog_product_outdated_price_values_cleanup is successfully finished. Statistics: {"sum":0.00076007843017578,"count":1,"realmem":0,"emalloc":1768,"realmem_start":141033472,"emalloc_start":129599000} [] []
[2020-09-18 10:37:02] main.INFO: Cron Job catalog_product_frontend_actions_flush is run [] []
[2020-09-18 10:37:02] main.INFO: Cron Job catalog_product_frontend_actions_flush is successfully finished. Statistics: {"sum":0.0011508464813232,"count":1,"realmem":0,"emalloc":1128,"realmem_start":141033472,"emalloc_start":129627224} [] []
[2020-09-18 10:37:02] main.INFO: Cron Job sales_grid_order_async_insert is run [] []
[2020-09-18 10:37:02] main.INFO: Cron Job sales_grid_order_async_insert is successfully finished. Statistics: {"sum":0.0004570484161377,"count":1,"realmem":0,"emalloc":752,"realmem_start":141033472,"emalloc_start":129721376} [] []
[2020-09-18 10:37:02] main.INFO: Cron Job sales_grid_order_invoice_async_insert is run [] []
[2020-09-18 10:37:02] main.INFO: Cron Job sales_grid_order_invoice_async_insert is successfully finished. Statistics: {"sum":0.00065398216247559,"count":1,"realmem":0,"emalloc":752,"realmem_start":141033472,"emalloc_start":129725040} [] []
[2020-09-18 10:37:02] main.INFO: Cron Job sales_grid_order_shipment_async_insert is run [] []
[2020-09-18 10:37:02] main.INFO: Cron Job sales_grid_order_shipment_async_insert is successfully finished. Statistics: {"sum":0.00047993659973145,"count":1,"realmem":0,"emalloc":752,"realmem_start":141033472,"emalloc_start":129727920} [] []
[2020-09-18 10:37:02] main.INFO: Cron Job sales_grid_order_creditmemo_async_insert is run [] []
[2020-09-18 10:37:02] main.INFO: Cron Job sales_grid_order_creditmemo_async_insert is successfully finished. Statistics: {"sum":0.00057697296142578,"count":1,"realmem":0,"emalloc":752,"realmem_start":141033472,"emalloc_start":129730896} [] []
[2020-09-18 10:37:02] main.INFO: Cron Job sales_send_order_emails is run [] []
[2020-09-18 10:37:02] main.INFO: Cron Job sales_send_order_emails is successfully finished. Statistics: {"sum":0.00070619583129883,"count":1,"realmem":0,"emalloc":736,"realmem_start":141033472,"emalloc_start":133777192} [] []
[2020-09-18 10:37:02] main.INFO: Cron Job sales_send_order_invoice_emails is run [] []
[2020-09-18 10:37:02] main.INFO: Cron Job sales_send_order_invoice_emails is successfully finished. Statistics: {"sum":0.00064396858215332,"count":1,"realmem":0,"emalloc":752,"realmem_start":141033472,"emalloc_start":134117160} [] []
[2020-09-18 10:37:02] main.INFO: Cron Job sales_send_order_shipment_emails is run [] []
[2020-09-18 10:37:02] main.INFO: Cron Job sales_send_order_shipment_emails is successfully finished. Statistics: {"sum":0.00058293342590332,"count":1,"realmem":0,"emalloc":752,"realmem_start":141033472,"emalloc_start":134397168} [] []
[2020-09-18 10:37:02] main.INFO: Cron Job sales_send_order_creditmemo_emails is run [] []
[2020-09-18 10:37:02] main.INFO: Cron Job sales_send_order_creditmemo_emails is successfully finished. Statistics: {"sum":0.00073099136352539,"count":1,"realmem":0,"emalloc":752,"realmem_start":141033472,"emalloc_start":134703952} [] []
[2020-09-18 10:37:02] main.INFO: Cron Job outdated_authentication_failures_cleanup is run [] []
[2020-09-18 10:37:02] main.INFO: Cron Job outdated_authentication_failures_cleanup is successfully finished. Statistics: {"sum":0.0012149810791016,"count":1,"realmem":0,"emalloc":1128,"realmem_start":141033472,"emalloc_start":134887872} [] []
[2020-09-18 10:37:03] main.INFO: Cron Job bulk_cleanup is run [] []
[2020-09-18 10:37:03] main.INFO: Cron Job bulk_cleanup is successfully finished. Statistics: {"sum":0.0011148452758789,"count":1,"realmem":0,"emalloc":2040,"realmem_start":141033472,"emalloc_start":134894720} [] []
[2020-09-18 10:37:03] main.INFO: 11 cron jobs were cleaned [] []
[2020-09-18 10:37:03] main.INFO: Cron Job enhancedprivacy_schedule is run [] []
[2020-09-18 10:37:03] main.INFO: Cron Job enhancedprivacy_schedule is successfully finished. Statistics: {"sum":0.00059700012207031,"count":1,"realmem":0,"emalloc":704,"realmem_start":141033472,"emalloc_start":138555080} [] []
[2020-09-18 10:37:04] main.INFO: Cron Job indexer_reindex_all_invalid is run [] []
[2020-09-18 10:37:04] main.INFO: Cron Job indexer_reindex_all_invalid is successfully finished. Statistics: {"sum":0.014595985412598,"count":1,"realmem":0,"emalloc":354848,"realmem_start":141033472,"emalloc_start":129101400} [] []
[2020-09-18 10:37:04] main.INFO: Cron Job indexer_update_all_views is run [] []
[2020-09-18 10:37:04] main.INFO: Cron Job indexer_update_all_views is successfully finished. Statistics: {"sum":0.011977910995483,"count":1,"realmem":0,"emalloc":90392,"realmem_start":141033472,"emalloc_start":129458360} [] []
[2020-09-18 10:37:04] main.INFO: Cron Job consumers_runner is run [] []
[2020-09-18 10:37:04] main.INFO: Consumer "async.operations.all" skipped as required connection "amqp" is not configured. Unknown connection name amqp [] []
[2020-09-18 10:37:04] main.INFO: Cron Job consumers_runner is successfully finished. Statistics: {"sum":0.0018670558929443,"count":1,"realmem":0,"emalloc":2736,"realmem_start":141033472,"emalloc_start":129426560} [] []
[2020-09-18 10:38:02] main.INFO: Cron Job catalog_product_outdated_price_values_cleanup is run [] []
[2020-09-18 10:38:02] main.INFO: Cron Job catalog_product_outdated_price_values_cleanup is successfully finished. Statistics: {"sum":0.00098395347595215,"count":1,"realmem":0,"emalloc":1768,"realmem_start":141033472,"emalloc_start":129585472} [] []
[2020-09-18 10:38:02] main.INFO: Cron Job catalog_product_frontend_actions_flush is run [] []
[2020-09-18 10:38:02] main.INFO: Cron Job catalog_product_frontend_actions_flush is successfully finished. Statistics: {"sum":0.001453161239624,"count":1,"realmem":0,"emalloc":1128,"realmem_start":141033472,"emalloc_start":129613696} [] []
[2020-09-18 10:38:02] main.INFO: Cron Job sales_grid_order_async_insert is run [] []
[2020-09-18 10:38:02] main.INFO: Cron Job sales_grid_order_async_insert is successfully finished. Statistics: {"sum":0.00071406364440918,"count":1,"realmem":0,"emalloc":752,"realmem_start":141033472,"emalloc_start":129707848} [] []
[2020-09-18 10:38:02] main.INFO: Cron Job sales_grid_order_invoice_async_insert is run [] []
[2020-09-18 10:38:02] main.INFO: Cron Job sales_grid_order_invoice_async_insert is successfully finished. Statistics: {"sum":0.00046014785766602,"count":1,"realmem":0,"emalloc":752,"realmem_start":141033472,"emalloc_start":129711512} [] []
[2020-09-18 10:38:02] main.INFO: Cron Job sales_grid_order_shipment_async_insert is run [] []
[2020-09-18 10:38:02] main.INFO: Cron Job sales_grid_order_shipment_async_insert is successfully finished. Statistics: {"sum":0.00058698654174805,"count":1,"realmem":0,"emalloc":752,"realmem_start":141033472,"emalloc_start":129714392} [] []
[2020-09-18 10:38:02] main.INFO: Cron Job sales_grid_order_creditmemo_async_insert is run [] []
[2020-09-18 10:38:02] main.INFO: Cron Job sales_grid_order_creditmemo_async_insert is successfully finished. Statistics: {"sum":0.00071620941162109,"count":1,"realmem":0,"emalloc":752,"realmem_start":141033472,"emalloc_start":129717368} [] []
[2020-09-18 10:38:02] main.INFO: Cron Job sales_send_order_emails is run [] []
[2020-09-18 10:38:02] main.INFO: Cron Job sales_send_order_emails is successfully finished. Statistics: {"sum":0.00067281723022461,"count":1,"realmem":0,"emalloc":736,"realmem_start":141033472,"emalloc_start":133763664} [] []
[2020-09-18 10:38:03] main.INFO: Cron Job sales_send_order_invoice_emails is run [] []
[2020-09-18 10:38:03] main.INFO: Cron Job sales_send_order_invoice_emails is successfully finished. Statistics: {"sum":0.00081896781921387,"count":1,"realmem":0,"emalloc":752,"realmem_start":141033472,"emalloc_start":134103632} [] []
[2020-09-18 10:38:03] main.INFO: Cron Job sales_send_order_shipment_emails is run [] []
[2020-09-18 10:38:03] main.INFO: Cron Job sales_send_order_shipment_emails is successfully finished. Statistics: {"sum":0.00091195106506348,"count":1,"realmem":0,"emalloc":752,"realmem_start":141033472,"emalloc_start":134383640} [] []
[2020-09-18 10:38:03] main.INFO: Cron Job sales_send_order_creditmemo_emails is run [] []
[2020-09-18 10:38:03] main.INFO: Cron Job sales_send_order_creditmemo_emails is successfully finished. Statistics: {"sum":0.00071501731872559,"count":1,"realmem":0,"emalloc":752,"realmem_start":141033472,"emalloc_start":134690424} [] []
[2020-09-18 10:38:03] main.INFO: Cron Job outdated_authentication_failures_cleanup is run [] []
[2020-09-18 10:38:03] main.INFO: Cron Job outdated_authentication_failures_cleanup is successfully finished. Statistics: {"sum":0.00092101097106934,"count":1,"realmem":0,"emalloc":1128,"realmem_start":141033472,"emalloc_start":134874344} [] []
[2020-09-18 10:38:03] main.INFO: Cron Job bulk_cleanup is run [] []
[2020-09-18 10:38:03] main.INFO: Cron Job bulk_cleanup is successfully finished. Statistics: {"sum":0.002554178237915,"count":1,"realmem":0,"emalloc":2040,"realmem_start":141033472,"emalloc_start":134881192} [] []
[2020-09-18 10:38:03] main.INFO: Cron Job magento_newrelicreporting_cron is run [] []
[2020-09-18 10:38:03] main.INFO: Cron Job magento_newrelicreporting_cron is successfully finished. Statistics: {"sum":0.00051212310791016,"count":1,"realmem":0,"emalloc":688,"realmem_start":141033472,"emalloc_start":136437616} [] []
[2020-09-18 10:38:03] main.INFO: Cron Job enhancedprivacy_schedule is run [] []
[2020-09-18 10:38:03] main.INFO: Cron Job enhancedprivacy_schedule is successfully finished. Statistics: {"sum":0.00067806243896484,"count":1,"realmem":0,"emalloc":672,"realmem_start":141033472,"emalloc_start":139535000} [] []
[2020-09-18 10:38:03] main.INFO: Cron Job consumers_runner is run [] []
[2020-09-18 10:38:03] main.INFO: Consumer "async.operations.all" skipped as required connection "amqp" is not configured. Unknown connection name amqp [] []
[2020-09-18 10:38:03] main.INFO: Cron Job consumers_runner is successfully finished. Statistics: {"sum":0.0018129348754883,"count":1,"realmem":0,"emalloc":2736,"realmem_start":141033472,"emalloc_start":129425448} [] []
[2020-09-18 10:38:04] main.INFO: Cron Job indexer_reindex_all_invalid is run [] []
[2020-09-18 10:38:04] main.INFO: Cron Job indexer_reindex_all_invalid is successfully finished. Statistics: {"sum":0.0089900493621826,"count":1,"realmem":0,"emalloc":354848,"realmem_start":141033472,"emalloc_start":129101400} [] []
[2020-09-18 10:38:04] main.INFO: Cron Job indexer_update_all_views is run [] []
[2020-09-18 10:38:04] main.INFO: Cron Job indexer_update_all_views is successfully finished. Statistics: {"sum":0.0090961456298828,"count":1,"realmem":0,"emalloc":90392,"realmem_start":141033472,"emalloc_start":129458360} [] []
[2020-09-18 10:38:04] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'product.reviews' element cannot be added as child to 'product_tabs', because the latter doesn't exist [] []
[2020-09-18 10:38:06] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'catalog.compare.sidebar' element cannot be added as child to 'sidebar.additional', because the latter doesn't exist [] []
[2020-09-18 10:38:06] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'sale.reorder.sidebar' element cannot be added as child to 'sidebar.additional', because the latter doesn't exist [] []
[2020-09-18 10:38:06] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'wishlist_sidebar' element cannot be added as child to 'sidebar.additional', because the latter doesn't exist [] []
[2020-09-18 10:38:06] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'footer.custom.block' tries to reorder itself towards 'copyright', but their parents are different: 'footer.content.bottom' and 'footer' respectively. [] []
[2020-09-18 10:38:06] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'authorization-link-login' tries to reorder itself towards 'register-link', but their parents are different: 'header.links' and 'top.links' respectively. [] []
[2020-09-18 10:38:06] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'store_language' tries to reorder itself towards 'store_switcher', but their parents are different: 'header.panel.right' and 'header.panel.store' respectively. [] []
```

Cron.log :

```
[2020-09-18 10:37:02] main.INFO: Cron Job catalog_product_outdated_price_values_cleanup is run [] []
[2020-09-18 10:37:02] main.INFO: Cron Job catalog_product_outdated_price_values_cleanup is successfully finished. Statistics: {"sum":0.00076007843017578,"count":1,"realmem":0,"emalloc":1768,"realmem_start":141033472,"emalloc_start":129599000} [] []
[2020-09-18 10:37:02] main.INFO: Cron Job catalog_product_frontend_actions_flush is run [] []
[2020-09-18 10:37:02] main.INFO: Cron Job catalog_product_frontend_actions_flush is successfully finished. Statistics: {"sum":0.0011508464813232,"count":1,"realmem":0,"emalloc":1128,"realmem_start":141033472,"emalloc_start":129627224} [] []
[2020-09-18 10:37:02] main.INFO: Cron Job sales_grid_order_async_insert is run [] []
[2020-09-18 10:37:02] main.INFO: Cron Job sales_grid_order_async_insert is successfully finished. Statistics: {"sum":0.0004570484161377,"count":1,"realmem":0,"emalloc":752,"realmem_start":141033472,"emalloc_start":129721376} [] []
[2020-09-18 10:37:02] main.INFO: Cron Job sales_grid_order_invoice_async_insert is run [] []
[2020-09-18 10:37:02] main.INFO: Cron Job sales_grid_order_invoice_async_insert is successfully finished. Statistics: {"sum":0.00065398216247559,"count":1,"realmem":0,"emalloc":752,"realmem_start":141033472,"emalloc_start":129725040} [] []
[2020-09-18 10:37:02] main.INFO: Cron Job sales_grid_order_shipment_async_insert is run [] []
[2020-09-18 10:37:02] main.INFO: Cron Job sales_grid_order_shipment_async_insert is successfully finished. Statistics: {"sum":0.00047993659973145,"count":1,"realmem":0,"emalloc":752,"realmem_start":141033472,"emalloc_start":129727920} [] []
[2020-09-18 10:37:02] main.INFO: Cron Job sales_grid_order_creditmemo_async_insert is run [] []
[2020-09-18 10:37:02] main.INFO: Cron Job sales_grid_order_creditmemo_async_insert is successfully finished. Statistics: {"sum":0.00057697296142578,"count":1,"realmem":0,"emalloc":752,"realmem_start":141033472,"emalloc_start":129730896} [] []
[2020-09-18 10:37:02] main.INFO: Cron Job sales_send_order_emails is run [] []
[2020-09-18 10:37:02] main.INFO: Cron Job sales_send_order_emails is successfully finished. Statistics: {"sum":0.00070619583129883,"count":1,"realmem":0,"emalloc":736,"realmem_start":141033472,"emalloc_start":133777192} [] []
[2020-09-18 10:37:02] main.INFO: Cron Job sales_send_order_invoice_emails is run [] []
[2020-09-18 10:37:02] main.INFO: Cron Job sales_send_order_invoice_emails is successfully finished. Statistics: {"sum":0.00064396858215332,"count":1,"realmem":0,"emalloc":752,"realmem_start":141033472,"emalloc_start":134117160} [] []
[2020-09-18 10:37:02] main.INFO: Cron Job sales_send_order_shipment_emails is run [] []
[2020-09-18 10:37:02] main.INFO: Cron Job sales_send_order_shipment_emails is successfully finished. Statistics: {"sum":0.00058293342590332,"count":1,"realmem":0,"emalloc":752,"realmem_start":141033472,"emalloc_start":134397168} [] []
[2020-09-18 10:37:02] main.INFO: Cron Job sales_send_order_creditmemo_emails is run [] []
[2020-09-18 10:37:02] main.INFO: Cron Job sales_send_order_creditmemo_emails is successfully finished. Statistics: {"sum":0.00073099136352539,"count":1,"realmem":0,"emalloc":752,"realmem_start":141033472,"emalloc_start":134703952} [] []
[2020-09-18 10:37:02] main.INFO: Cron Job outdated_authentication_failures_cleanup is run [] []
[2020-09-18 10:37:02] main.INFO: Cron Job outdated_authentication_failures_cleanup is successfully finished. Statistics: {"sum":0.0012149810791016,"count":1,"realmem":0,"emalloc":1128,"realmem_start":141033472,"emalloc_start":134887872} [] []
[2020-09-18 10:37:03] main.INFO: Cron Job bulk_cleanup is run [] []
[2020-09-18 10:37:03] main.INFO: Cron Job bulk_cleanup is successfully finished. Statistics: {"sum":0.0011148452758789,"count":1,"realmem":0,"emalloc":2040,"realmem_start":141033472,"emalloc_start":134894720} [] []
[2020-09-18 10:37:03] main.INFO: 11 cron jobs were cleaned [] []
[2020-09-18 10:37:03] main.INFO: Cron Job enhancedprivacy_schedule is run [] []
[2020-09-18 10:37:03] main.INFO: Cron Job enhancedprivacy_schedule is successfully finished. Statistics: {"sum":0.00059700012207031,"count":1,"realmem":0,"emalloc":704,"realmem_start":141033472,"emalloc_start":138555080} [] []
[2020-09-18 10:37:04] main.INFO: Cron Job indexer_reindex_all_invalid is run [] []
[2020-09-18 10:37:04] main.INFO: Cron Job indexer_reindex_all_invalid is successfully finished. Statistics: {"sum":0.014595985412598,"count":1,"realmem":0,"emalloc":354848,"realmem_start":141033472,"emalloc_start":129101400} [] []
[2020-09-18 10:37:04] main.INFO: Cron Job indexer_update_all_views is run [] []
[2020-09-18 10:37:04] main.INFO: Cron Job indexer_update_all_views is successfully finished. Statistics: {"sum":0.011977910995483,"count":1,"realmem":0,"emalloc":90392,"realmem_start":141033472,"emalloc_start":129458360} [] []
[2020-09-18 10:37:04] main.INFO: Cron Job consumers_runner is run [] []
[2020-09-18 10:37:04] main.INFO: Cron Job consumers_runner is successfully finished. Statistics: {"sum":0.0018670558929443,"count":1,"realmem":0,"emalloc":2736,"realmem_start":141033472,"emalloc_start":129426560} [] []
[2020-09-18 10:38:02] main.INFO: Cron Job catalog_product_outdated_price_values_cleanup is run [] []
[2020-09-18 10:38:02] main.INFO: Cron Job catalog_product_outdated_price_values_cleanup is successfully finished. Statistics: {"sum":0.00098395347595215,"count":1,"realmem":0,"emalloc":1768,"realmem_start":141033472,"emalloc_start":129585472} [] []
[2020-09-18 10:38:02] main.INFO: Cron Job catalog_product_frontend_actions_flush is run [] []
[2020-09-18 10:38:02] main.INFO: Cron Job catalog_product_frontend_actions_flush is successfully finished. Statistics: {"sum":0.001453161239624,"count":1,"realmem":0,"emalloc":1128,"realmem_start":141033472,"emalloc_start":129613696} [] []
[2020-09-18 10:38:02] main.INFO: Cron Job sales_grid_order_async_insert is run [] []
[2020-09-18 10:38:02] main.INFO: Cron Job sales_grid_order_async_insert is successfully finished. Statistics: {"sum":0.00071406364440918,"count":1,"realmem":0,"emalloc":752,"realmem_start":141033472,"emalloc_start":129707848} [] []
[2020-09-18 10:38:02] main.INFO: Cron Job sales_grid_order_invoice_async_insert is run [] []
[2020-09-18 10:38:02] main.INFO: Cron Job sales_grid_order_invoice_async_insert is successfully finished. Statistics: {"sum":0.00046014785766602,"count":1,"realmem":0,"emalloc":752,"realmem_start":141033472,"emalloc_start":129711512} [] []
[2020-09-18 10:38:02] main.INFO: Cron Job sales_grid_order_shipment_async_insert is run [] []
[2020-09-18 10:38:02] main.INFO: Cron Job sales_grid_order_shipment_async_insert is successfully finished. Statistics: {"sum":0.00058698654174805,"count":1,"realmem":0,"emalloc":752,"realmem_start":141033472,"emalloc_start":129714392} [] []
[2020-09-18 10:38:02] main.INFO: Cron Job sales_grid_order_creditmemo_async_insert is run [] []
[2020-09-18 10:38:02] main.INFO: Cron Job sales_grid_order_creditmemo_async_insert is successfully finished. Statistics: {"sum":0.00071620941162109,"count":1,"realmem":0,"emalloc":752,"realmem_start":141033472,"emalloc_start":129717368} [] []
[2020-09-18 10:38:02] main.INFO: Cron Job sales_send_order_emails is run [] []
[2020-09-18 10:38:02] main.INFO: Cron Job sales_send_order_emails is successfully finished. Statistics: {"sum":0.00067281723022461,"count":1,"realmem":0,"emalloc":736,"realmem_start":141033472,"emalloc_start":133763664} [] []
[2020-09-18 10:38:03] main.INFO: Cron Job sales_send_order_invoice_emails is run [] []
[2020-09-18 10:38:03] main.INFO: Cron Job sales_send_order_invoice_emails is successfully finished. Statistics: {"sum":0.00081896781921387,"count":1,"realmem":0,"emalloc":752,"realmem_start":141033472,"emalloc_start":134103632} [] []
[2020-09-18 10:38:03] main.INFO: Cron Job sales_send_order_shipment_emails is run [] []
[2020-09-18 10:38:03] main.INFO: Cron Job sales_send_order_shipment_emails is successfully finished. Statistics: {"sum":0.00091195106506348,"count":1,"realmem":0,"emalloc":752,"realmem_start":141033472,"emalloc_start":134383640} [] []
[2020-09-18 10:38:03] main.INFO: Cron Job sales_send_order_creditmemo_emails is run [] []
[2020-09-18 10:38:03] main.INFO: Cron Job sales_send_order_creditmemo_emails is successfully finished. Statistics: {"sum":0.00071501731872559,"count":1,"realmem":0,"emalloc":752,"realmem_start":141033472,"emalloc_start":134690424} [] []
[2020-09-18 10:38:03] main.INFO: Cron Job outdated_authentication_failures_cleanup is run [] []
[2020-09-18 10:38:03] main.INFO: Cron Job outdated_authentication_failures_cleanup is successfully finished. Statistics: {"sum":0.00092101097106934,"count":1,"realmem":0,"emalloc":1128,"realmem_start":141033472,"emalloc_start":134874344} [] []
[2020-09-18 10:38:03] main.INFO: Cron Job bulk_cleanup is run [] []
[2020-09-18 10:38:03] main.INFO: Cron Job bulk_cleanup is successfully finished. Statistics: {"sum":0.002554178237915,"count":1,"realmem":0,"emalloc":2040,"realmem_start":141033472,"emalloc_start":134881192} [] []
[2020-09-18 10:38:03] main.INFO: Cron Job magento_newrelicreporting_cron is run [] []
[2020-09-18 10:38:03] main.INFO: Cron Job magento_newrelicreporting_cron is successfully finished. Statistics: {"sum":0.00051212310791016,"count":1,"realmem":0,"emalloc":688,"realmem_start":141033472,"emalloc_start":136437616} [] []
[2020-09-18 10:38:03] main.INFO: Cron Job enhancedprivacy_schedule is run [] []
[2020-09-18 10:38:03] main.INFO: Cron Job enhancedprivacy_schedule is successfully finished. Statistics: {"sum":0.00067806243896484,"count":1,"realmem":0,"emalloc":672,"realmem_start":141033472,"emalloc_start":139535000} [] []
[2020-09-18 10:38:03] main.INFO: Cron Job consumers_runner is run [] []
[2020-09-18 10:38:03] main.INFO: Cron Job consumers_runner is successfully finished. Statistics: {"sum":0.0018129348754883,"count":1,"realmem":0,"emalloc":2736,"realmem_start":141033472,"emalloc_start":129425448} [] []
[2020-09-18 10:38:04] main.INFO: Cron Job indexer_reindex_all_invalid is run [] []
[2020-09-18 10:38:04] main.INFO: Cron Job indexer_reindex_all_invalid is successfully finished. Statistics: {"sum":0.0089900493621826,"count":1,"realmem":0,"emalloc":354848,"realmem_start":141033472,"emalloc_start":129101400} [] []
[2020-09-18 10:38:04] main.INFO: Cron Job indexer_update_all_views is run [] []
[2020-09-18 10:38:04] main.INFO: Cron Job indexer_update_all_views is successfully finished. Statistics: {"sum":0.0090961456298828,"count":1,"realmem":0,"emalloc":90392,"realmem_start":141033472,"emalloc_start":129458360} [] []
```

Note : Add product using API its added

API :

```
<?php
$url = "https://test.com/rest";
$token_url= $url."/V1/integration/admin/token";
$username= "test";
$password= "@test";
//Authentication REST API magento 2,
$ch = curl_init();
$data = array("username" => $username, "password" => $password);
$data_string = json_encode($data);
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL, $token_url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_string);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
'Content-Type: application/json'
));
$token = curl_exec($ch);
$adminToken= json_decode($token);
$headers = array('Content-Type:application/json','Authorization:Bearer '.$adminToken);
// Createt Product REST API URL
$apiUrl = $url."/V1/products";
$ch = curl_init();
$data = [
"product" => [
"sku" => "Test Product 1",
"name" => "Test Product 1",
"attribute_set_id" => 4,
"price" => 99,
"status" => 1,
"visibility" => 2,
"type_id" => "simple",
"weight" => "1",
"extension_attributes" => [
"category_links" => [
[
"position" => 0,
"category_id" => "5"
],
[
"position" => 1,
"category_id" => "7"
]
],
"stock_item" => [
"qty" => "1000",
"is_in_stock" => true
]
],
"custom_attributes" => [
[
"attribute_code" => "description",
"value" => "Description of product here"
],
[
"attribute_code" => "short_description",
"value" => "short description of product"
]
]
]
];
$data_string = json_encode($data);
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL, $apiUrl);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_string);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
$response = curl_exec($ch);
$response = json_decode($response, TRUE);
curl_close($ch)
```

Comment: Do you have any custom module enable? If yes, check by disabling it!

Comment: @BhaumikUpadhyay After migration don't install any custom extension.

Comment: Create new attribute set with minimal number of attributes, after that create new product with this attribute set. One of your attribute is causing this, so you have to find it.

Comment: @BartZalas What should i choose the field "Based On" while creating new Attribute Set. Screenshot: https://snipboard.io/SYb7aH.jpg

Comment: FYI My Attribute Set : Migration_Default: https://justpaste.it/36tvq & Default: https://justpaste.it/98tlt

Comment: Looks like it's lot in Default, try to remove as much as you can best creating new one like I wrote before.

Comment: This ware_house,  etc

Comment: Check your attribute set.issue in your attribute set group.

Comment: @JigarPatel  what i need to check? where should i debug? Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I had some issues during some migrations, I think these steps might help you.

### 1º Clean up

The first step will be to clean up your Magento install, so run this command below to clean up your product attributes that have not used and check the database.

```
wget https://files.magerun.net/n98-magerun2.phar && chmod +x ./n98-magerun2.phar && alias n98="./n98-magerun2.phar";
n98 setup:db:status && \
n98 db:maintain:check-tables && \
n98 catalog:product:attributes:cleanup
```

### 2º Disabling

Now we're going to disable all the third-party modules, so we're going to skip some possible incompatibility or issue due to these modules.

```
php bin/magento module:status | grep -v Magento | grep -v List | grep -v None | grep -v -e '^$' | xargs php bin/magento module:disable
```

### 3º Reinstall

The reinstall process solved many issues in my case, you don't need to do the entire migration again, you just need to remove the `env.php` and run the install process via CLI again. Remember to change the parameters in the install script.

```
mv app/etc/env.php app/etc/env.bkp
php -f ./bin/magento setup:install \
    --base-url=https://mystore.com/ \
    --use-secure=1 \
    --db-host=127.0.0.1 \
    --db-name=root \
    --db-user=root \
    --db-password=root \
    --admin-firstname=Rafael \
    --admin-lastname=Gomes \
    --admin-email=rafael@magento.com \
    --admin-user=admin \
    --admin-password=admin123 \
    --language=en_US \
    --currency=USD \
    --timezone=America/Sao_Paulo \
    --use-rewrites=1 \
    --backend-frontname=admin \
    --cleanup-database \
    --key=JkeEumwvvQBCDxypLPBozvrpF2rFNhNL
```

### 4º Final step

The final step will be putting it in developer mode again, reindex, cleaning cache and etc..

```
n98 deploy:mode:set developer && \
n98 s:upgrade && \
n98 c:enable && \
n98 i:reindex && \
n98 c:clean && \
n98 sys:check
```

Comment: I am installing Magento 2 from GitHub Installation, after successfully install during data migration connection stopped due to MySQL connection timeout, i just increase and again run from where migration stopped. So that my files under app/code/magento, not vendor/magneto. Are my steps cause this error?

Comment: I recommend checking the server requirements and use the installation via Composer and not via Github which is focused on development and tests.

Answer (score 0):

1. Try to remove `generated/code/*` and `var/cache/*`. Run the `php bin/magento indexer:reindex` and check again.
2. Check if the attribute `configurableExi...` has `frontend_label` value!  ((Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponentFactory->mergeMetadataElement(Array, '**configurableExi**...', NULL, false) #1) )
3. Check if `frontend_input` value of the attribute is valid and not null, try below query

```
SELECT * FROM `eav_attribute` WHERE `frontend_input` = '0'
```

If not correct then update the `frontend_input` value in `eav_attribute` table.

Hope this helps!

Comment: All my attribute set are empty, let me update that and share you the status.

Comment: @zus Are you able to solve the issue? Does solution work for you?

Comment: A new project getting the same error, I have doubt in the attribute set, I have tried so many combinations to solve still getting an error,

My attribute Set List: https://snipboard.io/siOSCK.jpg

One by One Attribute set:
 

https://justpaste.it/8lox7
 
Any help thanks.

Comment: There is no attribute group "Advanced Pricing" in both Default & Migration_Default Attribute Set.

Comment: I just updated my post, any help thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution

The way I resolved it was to go to Admin->Store->Attribute Set. And edited the Default and `Migration_Default` Attributes Set. Initially the `Migration_Default` Attribute had the attribute sets but the Default was empty. I added the attributes to the Default Attribute Set and executed the reindex command

```
php bin/magento indexer:reindex
```

Also make sure that the Schedule Design Update Group Contains the following attributes:

> custom_design_from 
>  custom_design_to
>  custom_design
> custom_layout

after check it

Comment: Shall i update what are all attribute available in Migration_Default to the Default attribute set right?

Comment: Adding

    custom_design_from
    custom_design_to
    custom_design
    custom_layout

to the Default Attribute set in the Schedule Design Update Group, and then executing `php bin/magento indexer:reindex`

Comment: Where is located https://docs.magento.com/user-guide/v2.3/catalog/product-scheduled-design-update.html ?

Comment: @zus here first check this comment :https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/5350#issuecomment-234512266
and after here also same issue they are some module disable and solve it , you can also look at https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/5350#issue-162914619

Comment: Following ths link : https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/5350#issuecomment-234512266 1) Run the command : UPDATE eav_attribute_group SET tab_group_code = "advanced", sort_order = 55 WHERE attribute_group_code = "schedule-design-update";   2) Default Attribute set : https://snipboard.io/T1M6h0.jpg & Migration_Default Attribute set : https://snipboard.io/tHuUnF.jpg 3) Run the command UPDATE catalog_product_entity SET created_in = "1"; Finally flush cache, compile, reindexed Still getting same error.

Comment: Anything else i missed out?

Comment: Any help further proceed?

Comment: There is no attribute group "Advanced Pricing" in both Default & Migration_Default Attribute Set.

Comment: I just updated my post, any help thanks.

Answer (score 0):

use This Command

```
php bin/magento indexer:reindex
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
php bin/magento cache:clean
```

Comment: yes, i did still i am facing an error

Answer (score 0):

I have faced this issue after migration. I did lots of analysis and found that due to blank records in the order tables.

Please follow the below steps to fix/remove blank value from the sales_order and sales_order_grid table.

- Check and remove the record from sales_order with null value on all column
- Query to find null record - SELECT * FROM `sales_order` WHERE `state` IS NULL

I hope this will help you.

Comment: My Magento version 2.3.4, in the database there is no table sales_flat_order'.

Comment: In my sales_order and sales_order_grid, few null values exits i just removed, still getting an error.

Comment: Did you clear Magento Cache and Please try to log out and login again.

Comment: Still getting same error

Comment: Let's have a quick chat? I will help you to fix this issue.

Comment: Okay sure.......

Comment: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/115760/https-magento-stackexchange-com-questions-318269-magento-2-3-after-migration-ad

Comment: backend_model, frontend_model, source_model : https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZfEp0.jpg

Comment: Please share code and db, so I can look into it quickly.

Comment: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/115760/https-magento-stackexchange-com-questions-318269-magento-2-3-after-migration-ad