# Magento 2.3 - Patch update stuck

Tags: patches, magento2.3.4, paypal-express

Almost 1 hour finished, still not complete.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**How to apply a composer patch for Magento Commerce and Open Source**

Upload the patch to your Magento root directory.
Run the following SSH command:

```
patch -p1 < %patch_name%.composer.patch
```

(If the above command does not work, try using -p2 instead of -p1)
For the changes to be reflected, refresh the cache in the Admin under System > Cache Management.

To apply a custom patch using Composer: https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/comp-mgr/patching/composer.html

**How to apply a github patch for Magento Commerce and Open Source**

If the Magento source code is located in `app/code/Magento` follow the same steps as above but use the github patch version.

```
patch -p1 < %patch_name%.github.patch
```

If you still have problems try running the command with verbose output:

```
-v            verbose (print errors/warnings while in event loop)
-vv           very verbose (also print client commands/reponses)
-vvv          extremely verbose (also print internal state transitions)
```

Comment: I did exactly what you said.

Comment: you mean : patch -p1 < PayPal_Express_Checkout_issue_fix_2.3.4_composer-2020-02-13-12-34-09.patch -vvv

Comment: How to solve this error : https://snipboard.io/aOArUw.jpg

Comment: I am trying with -p2 also not working

Comment: app/code/Magento/Paypal/Model/Api/Nvp.php

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/115903/discussion-between-zus-and-stevie-ray-hartog).

Comment: I just run the following command

Comment: patch -p1 < PayPal_Express_Checkout_issue_fix_2.3.4_github-2020-02-13-12-36-34.patch

Comment: Output : https://snipboard.io/n5qThy.jpg

Comment: Finally done :  patch -p0 <PayPal_Express_Checkout_issue_fix_2.3.4_github-2020-02-13-12-36-34.patch

Comment: any help https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/318269/57334 thanks

Comment: Please check if your product does have a valid attribute set.

Comment: Can you pls explain in brief

Comment: All my products have an attribute set, where should i focus?